# Не работает cron на debian

Tags: debian, cron, crontab

Исполняемый файл тут

```
/var/www/html/tools/test.php
```

содержимое файла test.php

```
<?php
fopen("test.txt", "a");
?>
```

Команда в кроне (nano /etc/crontab)

```
40 8    * * *   dev /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/tools/test.php
```

т.е., в 8.40 должен по идее был создаться файл test.txt.

Но не создается. Крон по какой-то причине не отрабатывает.

Не подскажете, что не так?

Comment: посмотрите в homedir пользователя dev, может вы просто не там ищите файл. Ну и в `/var/log/syslog` за соответствующее время.

Comment: в homedir нет его, искал даже через locate test.txt, предварительно проапдейтив базу updatedb. /var/log/syslog пустой

Comment: значит поищите место куда попадают логи крона. Может этот хипстерский systemd в себя их пишет. Ну а без логов стоит попробовать что-нибудь простое, `* * * * * root date > /tmp/crontest`. Затем последовательно усложнять.

Comment: И так не работает. Насколько я помню после сохранения файла /etc/crontab с правилами, ребут крона не требуется ведь?